# Editing Ruby Applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Testia Tarantula is a RoR testing suite running on Apache. After installing Ruby and Tarantula app on a CentOS server, I can access the web-based interface. Usually when I want to hack something open-source like Mantis, I change some code in the apache/Mantis folder or whatever and refresh the webpage. Even if I delete a whole wack of code, nothing seems to happen. If I make changes to a .js file in a Ruby app (or similar file), do I need to compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to restart the server. Rails (in production mode) precompiles the assets and it needs to be recompiled.

Answer (score 0):

If you change a js file then you have to reload the page at the very least. In production mode you pretty much need to restart the server if you change anything because your assets may be precompiled.

In development mode you don't have to restart the server for everything.  You can see changes in views and controllers without restarting but you do need to restart the server for changes to the model.

Running a local rails server is very useful from this point of view.  Just type rail -s on the command line and go to localhost:3000

Comment: Not enough rep to upvote. This isn't working anyways. I restart apache and still see no obvious changes to the ruby app (eg deleting a ton of obvious code). DO i need to started the Ruby service as well? I tried "rails -s" but it just shows me a help menu..

Comment: I was able to start a local rails server. Still 0 changes are showing up. Do you need to be a demi-god to use Ruby? holy unfriendly.

Comment: It should just change.  Not sure what problem you're having.

Comment: I used to do php a lot and much prefer rails now but there is a lot of learning curve.